# How to check if pipeline parameter is empty

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job which includes some parameters:
[image: Pipeline]

In the pipeline file I have the below code:

```
stage ("create bundle"){
            steps{
                script{
                        amd_distribution_create_bundle credential_id: params.DISTRIBUTION_CREDENTIAL_ID, distribution_url: params.DISTRIBUTION_URL, gps_credential_id: params.GPG_PASSPHRASE, bundle_name: params.BUNDLE_NAME, bundle_version: BUNDLE_VERSION
                }
            }
        }
```

how can I ask before calling the groovy method 'amd_distribution_create_bundle', if some field is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating the credentials parameter in jenkins job, you can specify `required: true`, then jenkins should validate the credentials paramter.

```
parameters {
    credentials(name: 'GPG_PASSPHRASE', defaultValue: '', credentialType: "Username with password", required: true )
}
```

You can also check the details mentioned in the link https://docwhat.org/jenkins-user-credentials

Adding Parameter

```
/* EXAMPLE */
parameters {
    credentials(
        credentialType: 'com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl',
        defaultValue: '',
        description: 'The credentials needed to deploy.',
        name: 'deployCredentialsId',
        required: true
    )
}
```

Using in the stage

```
/* EXAMPLE */
steps {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(
        credentialsId: '${deployCredentialsId}',
        usernameVariable: 'DEPLOY_USERNAME',
        passwordVariable: 'DEPLOY_PASSWORD',
    )]) {
        sh './my-command.bash --username="${DEPLOY_USERNAME}" --password="${DEPLOY_PASSWORD}"'
    }
}
```

If you just want to check if the variable is empty or not, you can check `isEmpty()` in groovy script. Your code can be as follows:

```
stage ("create bundle"){
        steps{
            script{
                    if ( GPG_PASSPHRASE.isEmpty()​​ ) {
                             GPG_PASSPHRASE = 'custom_string'
                     }
                    amd_distribution_create_bundle credential_id: params.DISTRIBUTION_CREDENTIAL_ID, distribution_url: params.DISTRIBUTION_URL, gps_credential_id: params.GPG_PASSPHRASE, bundle_name: params.BUNDLE_NAME, bundle_version: BUNDLE_VERSION
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: in my case it's not required, it can be empty. but I need to do some actions in that case, so how can I verify?

Comment: updated the answer to include the empty check as well.

Comment: I modified the question for a specific area.

Comment: You should have asked a new question or could have asked in comments rather than updating your complete question. For your previous question, the above answer was accepted. However, now you have updated the question, the answer doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Ok sorry. Will re edit this one again, accept the answer, and raise new one

Comment: Note that if you copy-paste the last code block in this answer you may get an invalid close-paren (it looks right but gets an error about a missing expected close-paren)